# What is a good Web search and web crawling engine for Java?

Tags: java, search-engine, web-crawler

I am working on an application where I need to integrate the search engine. This should do crawling also. Please suggest a good Java based search engine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nutch ([Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/about.html)) is an Open Source engine which should satisfy your needs.

Comment: Sorry I am adding this so late. First I explored this option used it and found it useful for me. Lucene is best option there might be othre like terrier but i din't explored it since I found every thing needed in Lucene. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

In the past I worked with [terrier](http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/terrier/), a search engine written in Java:

> Terrier is a highly flexible, efficient, effective, and robust search engine, readily deployable on large-scale collections of documents. Terrier implements state-of-the-art indexing and retrieval functionalities. Terrier provides an ideal platform for the rapid development of large-scale retrieval applications.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent the last 2 years developing our own high performance search engine with C. For Java I highly suggest Apache Lucene as Ajay mentioned above. For Java, it's the best in terms of speed, relevancy and features.

Comment: sorry, didn't read your complete post :P, if you need full package terrier is better in my opinion since lucene's(Nutch) crawler still young and i had few crashes while testing it couple months ago.

Comment: @John C: You can also edit your answer to add the additional information